# sample code for canceling the local notification in iphone

Tags: iphone

Sample code for canceling the local notification.

I am having a application which  sets a local notification and  now i want to cancel one of the local notification  set the by the application can someone provide the sample code for the same

Answer (score 1):

Cancel all local notifications with this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

(you actually just need the middle line.

---

Cancel one local notification with this line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:theNotification];
```

where `theNotification` is a `UILocalNotification` object, so in order to cancel a specific notification you need to hold on to it's `UILocalNotification`.

---

You can find more stuff in apple's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html